# Lookup data in one table and update another

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers

I need a trigger that fires on update of a particular column in a table, and updates other columns using data from two other tables.

Table 1 is called `STOCK_ITEMS`

The columns concerned are all foreign keys

- Column `STOCKGROUP` is FK for Table `STOCK_GROUPS`
- Column `STOCKGROUP2` is FK for Table `STOCK_GROUP2S`
- Column `X_STOCK_GROUP3` is FK for `X_STOCK_GROUP3S`

Table `X_STOCK_GROUP3S` contains the FKs of the other two stock group tables.
The idea is to make the first two columns dependent on the third, so that if the value of `X_STOCK_GROUP3` changes, this trigger will set the values of  `STOCKGROUP` and `STOCKGROUP2` using the data from `X_STOCK_GROUP3S`

I tried this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER STOCKGROUP
ON [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS]
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    IF UPDATE (X_STOCK_GROUP3)
       set STOCKGROUP = STOCK_GROUPS.GROUPNO

    PRINT 'AFTER UPDATE Trigger fired.'
GO
```

It does not work. It does not like my '=' sign. Or is there something else I'm missing (likely!!)

Any and all help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so here is the final, and successful, result:

**Kudos credit: Sonny Dhaliwal - Support Consultant - Enprise Solutions. Thanks Sonny.**

```
USE [MyDataBase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[X_SET_STOCK_GROUPS]
ON [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS]
FOR UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @STOCKCODE VARCHAR(100),
        @STOCKGROUP3 INTEGER,
        @STOCKGROUP1 INTEGER,
        @STOCKGROUP2 INTEGER
BEGIN

    SELECT @STOCKCODE = STOCKCODE FROM inserted
    SELECT @STOCKGROUP3 = X_STOCK_GROUP3 FROM inserted
    SELECT @STOCKGROUP1 = (SELECT SECONDARY_GROUP FROM X_STOCK_GROUP3S 
        WHERE SEQNO = @STOCKGROUP3)
    SELECT @STOCKGROUP2 = (SELECT PRIMARY_GROUP FROM X_STOCK_GROUP3S 
        WHERE SEQNO = @STOCKGROUP3)


    BEGIN
        UPDATE STOCK_ITEMS 
        SET STOCKGROUP = @STOCKGROUP1, STOCKGROUP2 = @STOCKGROUP2 
        WHERE STOCKCODE = @STOCKCODE
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Don' know if I understand what you want to do.
X_STOCK_GROUP3S contains some records like 
(ID,STOCKGROUP,STOCKGROUP2)
(21,1000,300)
(22,2000,200)
(23,3000,100)

and STOCK_ITEMS contains records like 
(ID,...,STOCKGROUP,STOCKGROUP2,X_STOCK_GROUP3)

If  X_STOCK_GROUP3 of table STOCK_ITEMS is updated to 21 you want to set the values STOCKGROUP to 1000 and STOCKGROUP2 to 300.

Is this what you want to accomplish?
Then your code is missing some selection criteria.
I would try something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER STOCKGROUP
ON [dbo].[STOCK_ITEMS]
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  IF UPDATE (X_STOCK_GROUP3)
    UPDATE STOCK_ITEMS SET STOCKGROUP = (
      SELECT STOCKGROUP FROM X_STOCK_GROUP3S 
      WHERE STOCK_ITEMS.X_STOCK_GROUP3 = X_STOCK_GROUP3S.ID
    ),
    STOCKGROUP2 = (
      SELECT STOCKGROUP2 FROM X_STOCK_GROUP3S 
      WHERE STOCK_ITEMS.X_STOCK_GROUP3 = X_STOCK_GROUP3S.ID
    )
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM deleted);
GO
```

Comment: OK, thanks Morty. I ended up paying a DBA to build me the trigger, code below for all who come accross this post looking for help.